# Remove the top level array and merge sub array into one

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array and I want to remove the top level array and merge all its sub array into one array.
Below is my array:

```
 $arr =   [KEY1] => Array
          (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [Feb] =>  120
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [Jan] =>  230
                )
            [3] => Array
                (
                    [Mar] =>  340
                )

         )

         [KEY2] => Array
         (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [Feb] =>  12
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [Jan] =>  23
                )
            [3] => Array
                (
                    [Mar] =>  34
                )
         )
```

I need to arrange and sort this array like below:
Output:

```
[KEY1] => Array
                (
                    [Jan] =>  230,
                    [Feb] =>  120,
                    [Mar] =>  340
                )
[KEY2] => Array
                (
                    [Jan] =>  23,
                    [Feb] =>  12,
                    [Mar] =>  34
                )
```

I have used

call_user_func_array('array_merge', $arr ); but not working.

Please suggest any wise way to do this.

Thanks

Comment: Check my edit portion for sorting functionality

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try like this as simple way,

```
     $arr = [
      'key1' =>[
          0 => ["feb" => 123],
          1 => ["dev" => 213],
          2 => ["jan" => 111],
      ],
      'key2' =>[
          0 => ["feb" => 132],
          1 => ["dev" => 321],
          2 => ["jan" => 555],
      ],
      ];
      $result = [];
      foreach($arr as $k => $v){
          foreach($v as $k1 => $v1){
              foreach($v1 as $k2 => $v2)
              $result[$k][$k2] = $v2;
          }
      }
      print_r($result);
```

Hope this will solve your problem.

**EDIT**

Here is your sorting function.

```
function sortNestedArray(&$a)
{
    sort($a);
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($a); $i++) {
        if (is_array($a[$i])) {
            sortNestedArray($a[$i]);
        }
    }
    return $a;
}
$a = sortNestedArray($result);
print_r($a);
```

Comment: Thanks bro #rahul_m